# JNI - is there a way to get JNI_OnUnload to be called by the JVM?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, jnienv

There is very little information about this, for example [this](http://bleaklow.com/2006/02/18/jni_onunload_mostly_useless.html) from 2006, and [people](https://github.com/mapbox/jni.hpp/blob/master/examples/hello.cpp) giving up on releasing JNI resources gracefully.

`JNI_OnUnload` ([Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#JNI_OnUnload)) is meant for releasing resources ("global refs" in particular) when your native functionality is no longer needed from within the JVM. A native library would be loaded like this

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("mylibjni"); // on Linux this translates to "libmylibjni.so"
}
```

... but Java offers no explicit way for unloading.

**What happens**: in my lib, because of not being given the opportunity to cleanup, the lib does eventually unload (I don't understand when, see below call stack), but too late, this triggers some global variables owning JNI *global refs* to call `DeleteGlobalRef` unsuccessfully:

```
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (10.0.2+13) (build 10.0.2+13)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (10.0.2+13, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libblahjni.so+0x9a7e6]  JNIEnv_::DeleteGlobalRef(_jobject*)+0x14
```

Digging into it, this is because of not having a `JNIEnv` on the thread doing the unloading (I'm caching the env on a `thread_local` basis). Trying to retrieve the Env at that time hasn't worked - I tried using `JavaVM::GetEnv` and `JavaVM::AttachCurrentThread` and it seems even though attaching works fine, `JavaVM::GetEnv` keeps returning `JNI_EDETACHED (-2)`. So presumably, it's too late in the JVM lifecycle to attach/have an env anymore.

Something else I've tried - as per 2006 article above, in Java I tried doing `System.runFinalizersOnExit(true)`, without luck. Even though I do see finalizers being invoked (as opposed to when not invoking runFinalizers, see below output), `JNI_OnUnload` is still not called.

```
Checked JNI functions are being used to validate JNI usage
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.Shutdown.runAllFinalizers ... JNI]
Checked JNI functions are being used to validate JNI usage
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.Shutdown.halt0 ... JNI]
```

As last piece of info, the lib unloading call stack looks like this. I don't understand where it's coming from. I'm on latest Arch linux, Java 10, I'm running in Docker if that matters. I'd like to sort out graceful exit principially and because that gives confidence that you are spotting problems occurring later in the project lifecycle, with ease.

```
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.Shutdown.runAllFinalizers ... JNI]
Checked JNI functions are being used to validate JNI usage
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.Shutdown.halt0 ... JNI]
 0# (some more code of my own ommitted at the top of the stack)
 1# std::_Optional_payload<...
 2# std::_Optional_base<...
 3# std::optional<...>::~optional() in /orion/mpf-jni/Debug/libmylibjni.so
 4# 0x00007FDCEC5E845C in /usr/lib/libc.so.6
 5# 0x00007FDCEC5E858E in /usr/lib/libc.so.6
 6# 0x00007FDCEB919B89 in /usr/lib/jvm/java-10-openjdk/lib/server/libjvm.so
 7# 0x00007FDCEBDF58C6 in /usr/lib/jvm/java-10-openjdk/lib/server/libjvm.so
 8# 0x00007FDCEBDF5346 in /usr/lib/jvm/java-10-openjdk/lib/server/libjvm.so
 9# 0x00007FDCEBDF2770 in /usr/lib/jvm/java-10-openjdk/lib/server/libjvm.so
10# 0x00007FDCEBDF3D2F in /usr/lib/jvm/java-10-openjdk/lib/server/libjvm.so
11# 0x00007FDCEBDF3FBE in /usr/lib/jvm/java-10-openjdk/lib/server/libjvm.so
12# 0x00007FDCEBC0558A in /usr/lib/jvm/java-10-openjdk/lib/server/libjvm.so
13# 0x00007FDCEC378A9D in /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
14# clone in /usr/lib/libc.so.6
  1447612069173.971  Fatal| could not get JVM env object for JNI version [65540], error [-2]
```